# Location manager: How to get the user Lats and Longs

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having problem showing my Latitude and Longitude in a Label, I've searched over the internet and compile all the result, here's what i got for now.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

class HomeVC: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet var myLong: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myLat: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func myLocation(sender: UIButton) {

        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {   

            var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate

            var myLatString = NSString(format:"%f",locValue.latitude) as String
            self.myLat.text = myLatString

            var myLongString = NSString(format:"%f",locValue.longitude) as String
            self.myLong.text = myLongString

        }

    }
```

I also add "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" for always usage. Now my problem is nothing happened when i press the button, its now showing my latitude and longitude. What is the problem with my code? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set your class as delegate for locationManager, when you call locationManager.startUpdatingLocation(), the method didUpdateLocations will be called automatically when the location is updated. So you shall not put didUpdateLocations inside the button event.

Besides that, you've defined locationManager two times in your code. Also, please use the code below to get the location coordinates from didUpdateLocations.

Maybe you want to call locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() when your button is pressed and get the location when locationManager call didUpdateLocations. This method should be implemented this way in your class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class HomeVC: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

@IBOutlet var myLong: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var myLat: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func myLocation(sender: UIButton) {
    // Maybe start updating location from here. it depends on the logic of your app.

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {   
    var locationArray = locations as NSArray
    var currentLocation = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
    var locValue = currentLocation.coordinate

    var myLatString = NSString(format:"%f",locValue.latitude) as String
    self.myLat.text = myLatString

    var myLongString = NSString(format:"%f",locValue.longitude) as String
    self.myLong.text = myLongString

}
```

Comment: i put locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() on the button and put the func locationManager outside the button, but i still got no value on the label. :(

Comment: @LEVISOGCPAS see my edited code, try to get the location using the code in didUpdateLocations.

Comment: yup, i used all the codes you provided, still got no lats and longs :(

Comment: Maybe if you change the level of accuracy you can quickly get a location https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy Also, have you set the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription property in your plist file?

Comment: Yes i did, how to change the level of accuracy?

Comment: I also saw that you defined locationManager *two times* in your code. I've edited again, see how I initialize the locationManager. You change the accuracy by setting locationManager.desiredAccuracy. You can see the other levels here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this:

```
  optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager!,
       didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
   // in locations you receive CLLocation objects.
}
```

Comment: it says, 'optional' can only be applied to protocol members